# Layout needing calendar glyphicon to be right next to input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am wanting my calendar glyphicon to be right next (to the right )  of the input but it is jumping down BELOW the input .

How can i fix

code

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="TickleDate" name="TickleDate" id="TickleDate" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate"
           #xdp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="tickleValue" [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx for the -1  troll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `input-group-addon` class in your anchor tag.

<sup>[**Reference Link**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups)</sup>

***Stack Snippet***

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="TickleDate" name="TickleDate" id="TickleDate" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" #xdp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="tickleValue" [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
    <a href="#" class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help..:)

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" class="form-control"...>`  is supposed to take the full width available (`col-xs-9` in your case). There are two ways to put the calendar icon in the same line as the input field:

1. Add class `input-group-addon` to the icon element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="TickleDate" name="TickleDate" id="TickleDate" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate"
           #xdp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="tickleValue" [bsConfig]="dpConfig">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. Use `col` class to control the width of input not taking the full width, leave some space for the icon.